# Value of Investment in the Past

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

An amount of $1000$ is to be accumulated at a compound rate of discount of $9$% per year. (a) Find the present value $3$ years before (b) Find the value of i corresponding to d.

For a) i have done the following:
$1000=X(1-0.09)^{-3}$

$X=0.19$

I am not sure on how to go on about (b).

Comment: For (a), did you mean $1000=X(1-0.09)^3$? I'm not sure if I understood it... What are i and d in (b)?

Comment: i used (-3) because they said to find the present valye 3 years "before". the before part has confused me

Comment: d=0.09 and i is what we need to find

Comment: Guest86 is asking what the variable $i$ *represents*, not what its value is. Apparently $d$ is the discount rate, but what is $i$ supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer is probably incorrect. It is left up in order for OP to provide clarification.

---

If you have \$1000 now and you want to know the value three years prior, \$1000 is your initial value. The relevant computation is therefore
$$
1000(1 - 0.09)^{-3} \approx 1327.01.
$$

An alternative approach is to say I have an initial value of $X$ that will be worth \$1000 in three years. In this case, you would solve
$$
1000 = X(1 - 0.09)^3
$$
and find $X \approx 1327.01$.

Comment: If you want the value three years ago, it should be less than \$1000, as there has been some interest since then to get to \$1000

Comment: @RossMillikan I mistook "rate of discount" to be "rate of depreciation". Should we instead be using $1 + 0.09$, or is discount something else entirely?

Comment: I suspect so, but am confused between discount rate and interest rate.

Answer (score 0):

For (b), it would seem to me that what you seek is a value of interest $i$ such that

$$1+i = \frac{1}{1-d}$$

where $d$ is the depreciation.  This then means that

$$i=\frac{d}{1-d} = \frac{0.09}{0.91} \approx 0.0989$$